# Oracle 12 get changed tables (inserted, deleted oder updated records)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, oracle19c

Is it possible in an Oracle 12/19 database to get a list of tables and its records which have changed/added/deleted within the last X month? The problem here is, that the tables do not have any kind of timestamp per record. Is this possible?

Comment: The basic answer is no. You can get something but not as you asked, not the records themselves but the SQL statements. If your orcale is running on archive mode it stores the executed SQL statements and you can query them like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-F35C6876-5AE0-4229-891D-47B1C3759A11.htm)

Comment: @Eldar: Tank you. And without the records. So just the tables which got new records within last x Months/Days. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes the table `V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS` has a column named `TABLE_NAME` it contains the table name if the SQL statement modifies a table and you can use `OPERATION` column to filter operations made on the table. For further [reading](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1154.htm#REFRN30132)

Comment: Can you add these comments aggregated as an answer to this question please, so that i mark it as solved/solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flashback Query](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/flashback-version-query-10g) to find the changes to a table in period of time/range of SCNs:

```
create table t (
  c1 int
);

exec dbms_lock.sleep ( 2 );
insert into t values ( 1 );
commit;
select current_scn from v$database;

CURRENT_SCN   
   19279246

exec dbms_lock.sleep ( 2 );
update t set c1 = 2;
commit;
delete t;
exec dbms_lock.sleep ( 2 );
commit;

select t.*, versions_operation, versions_startscn, versions_endscn 
from   t
  versions between scn 19279246 and maxvalue
order  by versions_startscn nulls first;

C1    VERSIONS_OPERATION       VERSIONS_STARTSCN    VERSIONS_ENDSCN   
    1 <null>                              <null>           19279250 
    2 U                                 19279250           19279253 
    2 D                                 19279253             <null>
```

The default window for this is small (900s). So it's highly unlikely you'll be able to go back and view changes from weeks or even hours ago. Enable [Flashback Data Archive](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1) to define how long you want to keep the history for.